# How to trigger airflow DAG *with configs* from another airflow DAG

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

Is it recommended, and what is the best way to trigger DAG A from DAG B with some configs passed to DAG A from DAG B?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TriggerDagRunOperator.

In the first DAG, insert the call to the next one as follows:

```
    trigger_new_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id=[task name],
    trigger_dag_id=[trigered dag],
    conf={"key": "value"},
    dag=dag
    )
```

This operator will start a new DAG after the previous one is executed.

Now you can download some configs passed to DAG A from DAG B by (for example) PythonOperator

```
def _take_data(**context):
    DAGA_data = context["dag_run"].conf

download_data_from_DAGA = PythonOperator(
    task_id='download_data_from_DAGA ',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=_take_data,
    dag=dag,
)
```

Documentation: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html